# how to create a thumbnail image from video without using ffmpeg in php

Tags: php

I want to create thumbnail image from video without using ffmpeg installation in php.I already created thumbnail image using ffmpeg. Right now i want is not using ffmpeg installation.

Comment: If it's problems with FFMpeg installation, i have used FFMpeg binary files. Used `exec()` function. No installation was made

Comment: @Justinas Do you have instructions on where to get the binaries and how to call them?